# ListView with ImageView and TextView, after Scrolling down an Up a random item is set

Tags: android, android-listview

I have a list with ImageView and TextView. I read a scann time and for the specified position of textview has to be set. This is done i a right way, but after srolling down and then up another textview in Listview is set. I am seeing that this is not new, but I could not solve this problem.Any idea?? BaseAdapter is in the following. I tried for more then a week but no solution

```
  @Override
        public View getView( final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

            if (convertView == null) {
                Log.d("convertView", "NULLL");


                convertView = LayoutInflater.from(mContenxt).inflate(
                        R.layout.list_items, null);

                holder = new ViewHolder();

                holder.textView = (TextView) convertView
                        .findViewById(R.id.placeName);

                holder.imageView = (ImageView) convertView
                        .findViewById(R.id.itemSymbole);

                holder.textDate = (TextView) convertView
                        .findViewById(R.id.txtViewTimeAndDate);

                holder.imageMap = (ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageViewMap);

                holder.linearLayoutText = ( LinearLayout)convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtViewList);


                holder.linearLayoutImage = ( LinearLayout)convertView.findViewById(R.id.thumbnail);

                convertView.setTag(holder);

            }
                Log.d("convertView", "Not NULLLL");
                holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();


            holder.id = position;

            holder.textView.setText(items.get(position).get("ProductName"));
            holder.imageView.setId(position);


            holder.linearLayoutText.setBackgroundColor(position);


            if (items.get(position).get("Identifier")
                    .equals(com.metasec.wachmann.ItemActivity.uID)) {

                holder.linearLayoutText.setBackgroundColor(Color.CYAN);

                holder.imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.ok);

                Log.d("TIMEEEE", ItemActivity.scannDateAndTime);

                holder.textDate.setText(ItemActivity.scannDateAndTime);
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }else {

               holder.imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.not_ok);
               holder.textDate.setText("");
               notifyDataSetChanged();
            }

            holder.linearLayoutText.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    holder.linearLayoutText.setBackgroundColor(position);
                    holder.linearLayoutText.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
                    notifyDataSetChanged();

                    String placeName = items.get(position).get("ProductName");
                    String identifier = items.get(position).get("Identifier");
                    String itemId = items.get(position).get("ItemId");
                    String propertyBaseId = null;

                    String gpsCoordinates = null;

                    GPSTracker gpsTracker = new GPSTracker(mContenxt);
                    gpsTracker.stopUsingGPS();

                    double latitude = 0;
                    double longitude = 0;

                    if (gpsTracker.canGetLocation()) {
                        latitude = gpsTracker.getLatitude();
                        longitude = gpsTracker.getLongitude();

                        gpsCoordinates = latitude + ", " + longitude;
                    }

                    for (int k = 0; k < LoggedActivity.propertyBaseList.size(); k++) {
                        if (LoggedActivity.propertyBaseList.get(k).getName()
                                .equals("xxxxxxx")) {

                            propertyBaseId = LoggedActivity.propertyBaseList.get(k)
                                    .getPropertyBaseId();


                            Intent intentSenderDataToServer = new Intent(mContenxt,
                                    SenderReportDemageToServerActivity.class);



                            // give ItemId
                            intentSenderDataToServer.putExtra(ITEM_ID, itemId);

                            // give GroupId
                            intentSenderDataToServer.putExtra(PRODUCT_NAME,
                                    placeName);

                            // give GroupName
                            intentSenderDataToServer.putExtra(IDENTIFIER,
                                    identifier);

                            // give PropertyBaseID
                            intentSenderDataToServer.putExtra(PROPERTY_BASE_ID,
                                    propertyBaseId);

                            // give GPS Coordinates
                            intentSenderDataToServer.putExtra(GPS_COORDINATES,
                                    gpsCoordinates);

                            Log.d("items.get(position).get(ProductNNNNName)", items
                                    .get(position).get("ProductName"));

                            intentSenderDataToServer.putExtra("ProductName",
                                    placeName);
                            intentSenderDataToServer.putExtra("Identifier",
                                    identifier);
                            mContenxt.startActivity(intentSenderDataToServer);

                        } // END IF Loop

                    } // END FOR Loop

                }
            });



            holder.imageMap.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    String placeName = items.get(position).get("ProductName");
                    String identifier = items.get(position).get("Identifier");
                    String itemId = items.get(position).get("ItemId");


                    Log.d("placeName11",placeName);
                    Log.d("identifier111",identifier);
                    Log.d("itemId111",itemId);

                    Intent intentWachmanMapActivitiy = new Intent(mContenxt,
                            WachmanOpenStreetMapViewActivity.class);


                    intentWachmanMapActivitiy.putExtra(ITEM_ID, itemId);

                    // give GroupId
                    intentWachmanMapActivitiy.putExtra(PRODUCT_NAME,
                            placeName);

                    // give GroupName
                    intentWachmanMapActivitiy.putExtra(IDENTIFIER,
                            identifier);

                    Log.d("items.get(position).get(ProductNNNNName)", items
                            .get(position).get("ProductName"));

                    intentWachmanMapActivitiy.putExtra("ProductName",
                            placeName);
                    intentWachmanMapActivitiy.putExtra("Identifier",
                            identifier);


                    mContenxt.startActivity(intentWachmanMapActivitiy);

                }
            });

            return convertView;
        }

        static class ViewHolder {
            TextView textView = null;
            TextView textDate = null;
            CheckBox checkbox = null;
            ImageView imageView = null;
            ImageView imageMap = null;
            ImageButton imageButtonMap = null;

            LinearLayout linearLayoutText = null;
            LinearLayout linearLayoutImage = null;
            int id;

        }
```

And the following class shows where my own adapter would be called. I backgroudn I have to call my adapter ofter and the previous time and figure has to be remained.

```
private class SendBackground extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Boolean>
{
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
          mProgDialog = new ProgressDialog(getBaseContext());
          mProgDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
          mProgDialog = ProgressDialog.show(ItemActivity.this, "Sending", " Please Wait" );

    }


    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... params) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub           
         return httpRequest.postData(itemIdTmp, propertyBaseIdtmp, uID, coordinatesTmp);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
        Log.d("SendBackground", "onPostExecute");

        if (result == true) {
            Log.d("onPostExecute", "TRUE");
            //mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);

            mProgDialog.dismiss();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Data sent..",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    /*----------------------------->>>> Whenever from Server True is return then my oown adapter hast to be adapted, as mentioned the state and time of previous items have to be remained */
            //setListAdapter(myBaseAdapterItemActivity);
            listView.setAdapter(myBaseAdapterItemActivity);
            myBaseAdapterItemActivity.notifyDataSetChanged();
        } else {

            mProgDialog.dismiss();

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "Sending Data to Server failed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .show();
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: if (items.get(position).get("Identifier") tell me What will be if this condition fail

Comment: Hi pawan yada, if this fails then nothing has to be done. I read from a tag, and in this listview wach of the item has a UID, and if the ID I read is the same then in the textview has to be set the time.

Comment: I mean  if failed what is the value of these field

 holder.linearLayoutText.setBackgroundColor(Color.CYAN);

  holder.imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.ok);

Comment: In a linearlayout, I have two textview-s, so if that condition is field then the hole Linearlayout(  holder.linearLayoutText.setBackgroundColor(Color.CYAN)) has to be highlighted, and imageview has to be from not OK to OK in the listview

Answer (score 0):

// read all comments i write where need modifiaction
// Do not call notifiy dataset change inside adapter.
// if it will not work then i will write a sample code

```
@Override
 public View getView( final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

     ViewHolder holder = null; // use it 

     if (convertView == null) {
         Log.d("convertView", "NULLL");


         convertView = LayoutInflater.from(mContenxt).inflate(
                 R.layout.list_items, null);

         holder = new ViewHolder();

         holder.textView = (TextView) convertView
                 .findViewById(R.id.placeName);

         holder.imageView = (ImageView) convertView
                 .findViewById(R.id.itemSymbole);

         holder.textDate = (TextView) convertView
                 .findViewById(R.id.txtViewTimeAndDate);

         holder.imageMap = (ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageViewMap);

         holder.linearLayoutText = ( LinearLayout)convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtViewList);


         holder.linearLayoutImage = ( LinearLayout)convertView.findViewById(R.id.thumbnail);

         convertView.setTag(holder);

     } else {
         holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag(); // new changes
         Log.d("convertView", "Not NULLLL");
     }

     holder.id = position;

     holder.textView.setText(items.get(position).get("ProductName"));
     holder.imageView.setId(position); // why you set position it will cause error


     //holder.linearLayoutText.setBackgroundColor(position);


     if (items.get(position).get("Identifier")
             .equals(com.metasec.wachmann.ItemActivity.uID)) {

         holder.linearLayoutText.setBackgroundColor(Color.CYAN);

         holder.imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.ok);

         Log.d("TIMEEEE", ItemActivity.scannDateAndTime);

         holder.textDate.setText(ItemActivity.scannDateAndTime);
        // notifyDataSetChanged(); no need to call it.
     }else {

        holder.imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.not_ok);
        holder.linearLayoutText.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
        holder.textDate.setText("");
        //notifyDataSetChanged(); no need to call it.
     }

     holder.linearLayoutText.setTag(position);
     holder.linearLayoutText.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

         @Override
         public void onClick(View v) {

            // holder.linearLayoutText.setBackgroundColor(position);
             holder.linearLayoutText.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
            // notifyDataSetChanged();

             int selectedPosition = (Integer)v.getTag();

             String placeName = items.get(selectedPosition).get("ProductName");
             String identifier = items.get(selectedPosition).get("Identifier");
             String itemId = items.get(selectedPosition).get("ItemId");
             String propertyBaseId = null;

             String gpsCoordinates = null;

             GPSTracker gpsTracker = new GPSTracker(mContenxt);
             gpsTracker.stopUsingGPS();

             double latitude = 0;
             double longitude = 0;

             if (gpsTracker.canGetLocation()) {
                 latitude = gpsTracker.getLatitude();
                 longitude = gpsTracker.getLongitude();

                 gpsCoordinates = latitude + ", " + longitude;
             }

             // you are starting activity in lop it is dangerous because
             // you are launching many activity.
             // you should pass array 
             // i do not know are requirement.

             for (int k = 0; k < LoggedActivity.propertyBaseList.size(); k++) {
                 if (LoggedActivity.propertyBaseList.get(k).getName()
                         .equals("xxxxxxx")) {

                     propertyBaseId = LoggedActivity.propertyBaseList.get(k)
                             .getPropertyBaseId();


                     Intent intentSenderDataToServer = new Intent(mContenxt,
                             SenderReportDemageToServerActivity.class);



                     // give ItemId
                     intentSenderDataToServer.putExtra(ITEM_ID, itemId);

                     // give GroupId
                     intentSenderDataToServer.putExtra(PRODUCT_NAME,
                             placeName);

                     // give GroupName
                     intentSenderDataToServer.putExtra(IDENTIFIER,
                             identifier);

                     // give PropertyBaseID
                     intentSenderDataToServer.putExtra(PROPERTY_BASE_ID,
                             propertyBaseId);

                     // give GPS Coordinates
                     intentSenderDataToServer.putExtra(GPS_COORDINATES,
                             gpsCoordinates);

                     Log.d("items.get(position).get(ProductNNNNName)", items
                             .get(position).get("ProductName"));

                     intentSenderDataToServer.putExtra("ProductName",
                             placeName);
                     intentSenderDataToServer.putExtra("Identifier",
                             identifier);
                     mContenxt.startActivity(intentSenderDataToServer);

                 } // END IF Loop

             } // END FOR Loop

         }
     });

     holder.imageMap.setTag(postion);

     holder.imageMap.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

         @Override
         public void onClick(View v) {
             // TODO Auto-generated method stub
             int selectedPosition = (Integer)v.getTag();
             String placeName = items.get(selectedPosition).get("ProductName");
             String identifier = items.get(selectedPosition).get("Identifier");
             String itemId = items.get(selectedPosition).get("ItemId");


             Log.d("placeName11",placeName);
             Log.d("identifier111",identifier);
             Log.d("itemId111",itemId);

             Intent intentWachmanMapActivitiy = new Intent(mContenxt,
                     WachmanOpenStreetMapViewActivity.class);


             intentWachmanMapActivitiy.putExtra(ITEM_ID, itemId);

             // give GroupId
             intentWachmanMapActivitiy.putExtra(PRODUCT_NAME,
                     placeName);

             // give GroupName
             intentWachmanMapActivitiy.putExtra(IDENTIFIER,
                     identifier);

             Log.d("items.get(position).get(ProductNNNNName)", items
                     .get(position).get("ProductName"));

             intentWachmanMapActivitiy.putExtra("ProductName",
                     placeName);
             intentWachmanMapActivitiy.putExtra("Identifier",
                     identifier);
             mContenxt.startActivity(intentWachmanMapActivitiy);

         }
     });

     return convertView;
 }

 static class ViewHolder {
     TextView textView = null;
     TextView textDate = null;
     CheckBox checkbox = null;
     ImageView imageView = null;
     ImageView imageMap = null;
     ImageButton imageButtonMap = null;

     LinearLayout linearLayoutText = null;
     LinearLayout linearLayoutImage = null;
     int id;

 }
```

Comment: Tell me if it working or not, txtDate and layout background update acording to you data.

Comment: Hi  pawan yadav, Thank you very much, solve this Problem.But I have one question maybe you could help me. How can I save the state of Listview. e.g. If the item on list for example at position 10, the textDate, and imageView is set, then time and image should be save this means seen. And if I click on item 12 then i should se the text date in position 10 and in position 12 the another scannim time and also the imageview should be set to OK. I do not know if I could explain what I want. I call Adapter more times, e.g. 30 times, and each time, the state shoould be saved.

Comment: Your explanation is not clear you means

When i click on position 12 then at position 12 new scanning time is set and imageview image  changed to ok

Comment: Yes, but the scanning time and imageview ok at position 10 should stay. And now at position 12 imageview should change to Ok and also a new scanning time. So now if a click at position 15, the imageview and scanning time at positions 10 ,12 should stay, and at position 15 the imageview has to be set to Ok and also a new scanning time.

Comment: thank you, listView.setAdapter(myBaseAdapterItemActivity) is calling more times. this means, I want always the settedTxtDate and imageView to be remained.

Comment: Adapter will take care of it. I modify code .I hope it will work. Now i only change the text you can modify according to your need.

Comment: The problem is that, If i click on Image it should automatically start an activity, if I click on  holder.linearLayoutText it should start another activity.   listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener()) I had it before, but could not manage the list. i know daapter should take care of it but I set holder.textView, holder.imageMap nd the other are set in Adapter. So whenever I touch on the display the getview is called. This is right, but it updates always from the beginning.

Comment: You did not set onclick listener to image and linearlayoutText so how new activity started.

Comment: I did it but I forgot to post it. This means, my main point is how keep the textView and Imageview remained?

Comment: @ pawan yadav . I know it is a little bit complicated, because the old state in this case image and text ahst to be saved(shown). in getView I have to improve but no idea how.

Comment: could you send me your email adress, otherwise I can send hier after a few hours, due to stackoverflow hours limitation

Comment: yes pawan_gp2000@yahoo.co.in

right now i am in office . I will work on problem when i will go to home

Comment: @pawan_gp I send my Code in Edite version, Please you can find it at the beginning.

Comment: @pawan_gp sorry for bothering, but have you seen my editted version at the beginning?

Comment: I am busy because urgent work so i am try to resolve as soon as posible

Comment: I how you hade a great weekend, but I am still havin the same problem an nto jet fixed. I hope you had a little bit time

Comment: Sorry, i assume that this problem is solved so i did not reply.

Comment: Unfortunatelly not. I edited my Source code. I have to change something my baseadapter which has to keep always the old state